# Touch Drag Exit Kotlin

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin

I have a Swift iOS project that I am converting to Android using Kotlin.
I have a particular button that has three events associated with it.  Touch Down, Touch Drag Exit and Touch Up Inside.
Essentially, what this does is when I tap and hold on the bitton, other items are made visible.  When I release, or drag outside the button, the other items are hidden again.

Simple:

```
 @IBAction func showHintsButtonTouchDown(_ sender: UIButton) {
    showHideHints(true)
}

@IBAction func showHintsButtonTouchUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
    showHideHints(false)
}

@IBAction func showHIntsButtonDragExit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    showHideHints(false)
}
```

I want to do the same in my Kotlin project.
So far, I am doing this:

```
 hintsButton.setOnLongClickListener {
        showHideHints(true)
        false
 }


 hintsButton.setOnClickListener {
        showHideHints(false)
 }
```

And this handles the event when I touch down and hold on the button the setOnLongClickListener fires and if my finger does not leave the button and I release, the setOnCLickListener fires.
However, if I drag away from the button and release my finger, the objects remain visible.
Is there another way to accomplish what I am wanting to do?

Comment: You need to go deeper than the longPress/longClick events. You're looking at the onTouch method (here's a good example : http://codetheory.in/android-ontouchevent-ontouchlistener-motionevent-to-detect-common-gestures/ )

Comment: Excellent. That is what I was looking for.